# Rails exceptions to pluralising controller names?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am building a very basic twitter-like application.

I would like to have mydomain.com/trending however I am aware that the convention would be to have "trendings" for the controller name and thus the url also - which doesn't make much sense to me, what is the best way around this, do we just mask the url some how? Or are their certain exceptions to the pluralising of controllers/views?

Comment: You can use any URL you want. You just have to setup [routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) correctly. [This section](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#naming-routes) is relevant to your question.

Comment: That's what I guessed, mainly i am interested in the controller, should it be called trendings for the sake of convention even though the name sounds kind of unintuitive. I feel like I'm missing something here or looking at it the wrong way.

If you have a page that showed trending tweets, would you use the tweets controller with an action that displays them trending or a trendings controller?

Comment: I would say that the resource is tweets and that trending tweets are just a collection of special tweets that are trending. Therefore I would create `def trending` in your `TweetsController`. If you still want `/trending`, you can do `get 'trending', to: 'tweets#trending', as: :trending` in routes.

Comment: @Melbourne2991 You should post the solution as a answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your routes file do something like this

```
get 'trending', to: 'tweets#trending', as: :trending
```